# How do I change the stroke color while retaining the fill color using eye dropper in Illustrator?

Tags: colors, adobe-illustrator

I have a question regarding illustrator.

Let's say I have a circle with blue fill and red stroke.
And I place an image in the illustrator file.
Now I want to change the red stroke of my circle to let's say a purple color by sampling the color from the image.

How can I achieve that with a eye dropper tool?
Every time when I try to sample a color from the image, the whole circle will change to purple instead of just the stroke?

I have tried multiple key combination, shift, alt, ctrl but they all don't work.

Cheers,
Venn.

Answer (score 4):

hold SHIFT while using the color picker and it will pick either the fill color or the stroke color, depending on which one is in the foreground on the color picker panel or the toolbar. (you can switch that with X)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. I have wondered about that as well, and I think the tool automatically puts it as a fill colour. For just a few operations, I would unselect the object, pick the colour, then copy the hexadecimal code and paste it for the other object.

I think your most efficient technique is:

Select all objects and reverse their stroke and fill colours, then use the eyedrop thingie to change their fill colour. Once you're done, reselect everything and re-reverse their stroke and fill coulours. This should be the result you want.

Alternatively:

If every object needs the same stroke, you could try adding the stroke to the layer's aspect, so it applies to every object. Simple and quick.

You can also fiddle with the menu that enables you to redefine the colours in selected objects, in the Edit menu.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a long-standing fault in the way that Illustrator's Eyedropper tool works.

To set a stroke colour based on an image, you'll need to do the following steps:

1) **Make sure everything is deselected in your document, and the image you want to sample is on-screen.**

2) Select the Eyedropper tool, move it over the image and click on the area you want to sample.

3) Illustrator changes the default fill colour to the one you've selected. If you don't have the Colour and Swatches panels open, do so now either from the Window menu or by selecting a workspace that contains them. (Essentials has these by default, but you'll need to click on the little **<<** button if they're currently collapsed to icons only)

4) Click on the fill colour in the Colour panel to select it, then click and drag it to the Swatches panel.

5) Now, select the object(s) whose stroke colours you want to change, make sure to click the stroke colour in the Colour panel, then click on the sampled colour in the Swatches panel to apply it to the selected object(s).

If you're going to sample several colours from an image to use in a document, you should consider giving them appropriate names in the Swatches panel so that you can find them later. To do that, just double-click on the colour in the Swatches panel (make sure to deselect all objects **BEFORE** doing this!) then type a description (eg. Skintone, Aubergine, Brickwork) and click OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the eye dropper to get the color profile, then copy down all of the degrees and numbers that make up that color and re-enter them for the stroke color!